# Delimiting words in a SAS macro variable

Tags: macros, sas, delimiter

Say I have a macro varaiable x that can contain any number of alpha-only words each separated by one or more spaces:

```
%let x =   A B      CD   ;
```

I want to create another macro variable that will give this result when printed (single quotes could also be exchanged for double quotes):

```
'A','B','CD'
```

It's for use in an `in()` statement... ie. I'd to write code that looks something like this:

```
data want;
  set have;
  where my_field in (   /* DO SOMETHING TO &X HERE TO GIVE DESIRED OUTPUT */  ) ;
run;
```

I'm looking for a (preferably one-line) pure-macro code solution.  One that doesn't generate this note:

```
NOTE 49-169: The meaning of an identifier after a quoted string might change in a
future SAS release.  Inserting white space between a quoted string and the succeeding
identifier is recommended.
```

So far I have this:

```
%let y = %str(%')%sysfunc(tranwrd(  %sysfunc(compbl(&x)) ,%str( ),%str(%',%') ))%str(%');
%put &y;
```

But I can't get rid of that darn note.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the macro language?  This sounds like data manipulation to me.

Comment: Answer updated to address your question.  The value in `&x` is passed into SAS as a parameter.

Comment: Couldn't you use `indexw` instead of `in` for your if condition and get the same result without having to worry about inserting lots of quotes? See my answer below.

Comment: @user667489  Yes - given my original example piece of code you are right.  It was a bad example though as I actually should have had it in a `where` statement to take advantage of indexes. I've modified it now.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the FCMP try with CATS(), you need to add an `LENGTH` statement for the result variable.  FCMP handles character variables slightly differently from the Data Step.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.funcs;

  function delimit_words(iString $) $; 
    length result $200; 
    result = cats("'",tranwrd(cats(compbl(iString))," ", "','"),"'");    
    return (result );
  endsub;

run;

options cmplib=work.funcs;

data _null_;
  x = "  A  B  C   ";
  y = delimit_words(x);
  put y=;
run;
```

Returns:

```
5136   data _null_;
5137     x = "  A  B  C   ";
5138     y = delimit_words(x);
5139     put y=;
5140   run;

y='A','B','C'
```

Comment: Great thanks - looks like I should go and read the documentation for FCMP sometime rather than just blindly using it =P

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  The trick was when adding quotes, to make sure they weren't adjacent to the word boundaries by inserting a space.  So initially the string is padded with additional spaces.  Then right at the end, I remove the additional spaces with `compress()`.  That way we can sneak past the test for quoted string identifiers!

```
%let x =   A  B  C   ;
%let y = %sysfunc(compress(%str(%' )%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(compbl(&x)), %str( ), %str( %',%' ) ))%str( %') ));
%put &y;
```

Result:

```
'A','B','C'
```

Kinda ugly though.

**EDIT:  2nd Attempt:**

Thought I'd cheat and use `proc fcmp`.  End result is much nicer:

```
proc fcmp outlib=common.funcs.funcs;

  function delimit_words(iString $) $;    
    result = "'" || tranwrd(cats(compbl(iString))," ", "','") || "'";    
    return (result );
  endsub;

run;
```

Datastep example:

```
data x;
  x = "  A  B  C   ";
  y = delimit_words(x);
  put y=;
run;
```

Improved macro example:

```
%let x =   A  B  C   ;
%let y = %sysfunc(delimit_words(&x));
%put &y;
```

For some reason `proc fcmp` was giving me unexpected results if I tried to use the `cats()` function instead of the `||` concatenators so I just went with `||`.  The function could be improved by allowing the user to specify what symbol(s) constitute a word boundary, as well as whether or not to quote the output, and if so, whether to use single or double quotes... but I'll add those in on an as-needed basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your if condition to use indexw instead of in then I think you can avoid this problem entirely:

```
data want;
  set have;
  if indexw("&X",my_field) then do; 
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  See my updated comments against the original question though.